# Override default value of TextBox.TextProperty

Tags: wpf, textbox, dependency-properties

I have a custom control that derives from TextBox. And I cannot find a way to override the default Text value. So, in short - I want MyTextBox to have some specific default text in it.

The code:

```
    public class MyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        static MyTextBox()
        {
            TextBox.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(MyTextBox), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("DEFAULT TEXT", OnTextChanged));
        }

        private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the property (strangely) contains the "DEFAULT TEXT" value, yet it does not show up in the UI (text box is empty).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why have you set your constructor to `static`?

Comment: Are you subclassing just for the sake of having a different default value for text property?

Comment: Isn't <TextBox Text="DEFAULT TEXT"> enough?  Just add a trigger to make sure a button or something is disabled until the text changes.

Comment: `static` is for overriding the property metadata only once; no, the default value is a tiny bit of the whole subclass.

Comment: `<TextBox Text="DEFAULT TEXT">` isn't enough, since I would have to always write it through XAML. Same goes with creating a style (even with a default style I will have to always remember to set `BasedOn` for every style). Plus I need much more than just the default value changed => the most logical place for this is overriding the default property value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TextBox uses an inner class to provide most of it's functionality. This same class is shared with RichTextBox. I believe the TextBox assumes Text will be empty when constructed, so the UI is not updated.

One thing to keep in mind is that you have effectively short-circuited the TextBox.OnTextPropertyChanged method from being called. If you want to override the PropertyChangedCallback, then you'd probably need to manually call the TextBox version to ensure everything works as expected.

You can get to the base class's PropertyChangedCallback using TextProperty.[GetMetadata(typeof(TextBox))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597487.aspx).PropertyChangedCallback.

You may be able to call the TextBox's PropertyChangedCallback in an instance constructor to force the UI to update. Otherwise, you'd need to set Text directly.

Comment: Thanks! As soon as I started calling the PropertyChangedCallback in the instance constructor and in my callback it all started working! :)